# Failed to Enable Constraints when querying from TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, constraints, tableadapter

I have created a query in a table adapter I have in a static class, that executes the following query:

```
SELECT
    d.Date, c.Activity, b.Balance
FROM
    dbo.BalanceImport b
LEFT JOIN dbo.CashActivity c ON c.Sequence = b.Seq_CashActivity
LEFT JOIN dbo.dimDate d ON d.Sequence = b.Seq_dimDate
WHERE
    d.Date = @Date
```

The code that calls this is as follows:

```
public static DataView GetImportByDate(DateTime importDate)
{
    return _BalanceImportTableAdapter.GetBAIByDate(importDate.ToShortDateString()).DefaultView;
}
```

However, when I call this, I get the following error message:

`Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.`

FWIW, We used Erwin to model out the data, which in turn auto-generated a few triggers in our DB, however I have all of those disabled at the moment.

It's working when I manually run the query in SSMS, and when I test it in the Query Builder of the DataSet, but not when I run the code.

The Stack Trace brings me to the following generated code for the `BAIImportTable` Adapter method:

```
public virtual FinanceDWDataSet.BalanceImportDataTable GetBAIByDate(string Date) {
    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[1];
    if ((Date == null)) {
        throw new global::System.ArgumentNullException("Date");
    }
    else {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((string)(Date));
    }
    FinanceDWDataSet.BalanceImportDataTable dataTable = new FinanceDWDataSet.BalanceImportDataTable();
    this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: what is the return type of GetBAIByDate? I meant to ask if it is a default DataTable or some custom datatable?

Comment: I'm looking at the stack trace in the DataSet code and it looks like it's returning a `BAIImportDataTable`.... which is odd.... I'm thinking I might need to execute the query outside of the dataset?

Comment: I wound up creating a customized `DataTable` and `TableAdapter` for this, but I'm curious to see if anyone comes up with another solution

Comment: Can you check the FinanceDWDataSet.xsd file and then to BalanceImportDataTable table and verify Date and Activity column allows nulls?

Comment: That table doesn't actually have a date column

Comment: And that looks like that's the issue

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: I wound up creating a custom `DataTable` to handle that particular query, and that's working